# Labels for Animated Donut Chart D3

Tags: animation, d3.js

I am trying to label my animated Donut using D3...Can change data and get the drop-down to work but am having trouble labeling the donuts....Here is my code

```
var radius = 74,
    padding = 10;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#aec7e8", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#bdbdbd", "#8c564b", "#d62728", "#17becf", "#7f7f7f",    "#bcbd22", "#393b79","#31a354"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
   .outerRadius(radius)
   .innerRadius(radius - 50);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
   .sort(null)
   .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; }));

data.forEach(function(d) {
d.DataUnitID = color.domain().map(function(name) {
  return {name: name, population: +d[name]};
});
});

var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("width", radius * 2)
  .attr("height", radius * 3.5)
.selectAll("g")
  .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 16)
  .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });

var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll(".pie")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("svg")
  .attr("class", "pie")
  .attr("width", radius * 2)
  .attr("height", radius * 2)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(function(d) { return pie(d.DataUnitID); })
 .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "arc")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.name); });

svg.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.State; });



});
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/GQDUS/)?

Comment: haven't been able to get this to work with the animated donut...

Comment: So what have you tried to make it work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/goatety/5VEAa/2/   added var vis on from your example....still no luck...still working on it...thanks Lars

Comment: I had a look at your code. It renders the label the donuts for me. What trouble are you having with the label? Here's my document: http://vida.io/documents/JqJfznPPjFvSTH5uF